# What’s the difference between 吃上饭 and 吃下饭?

Tags: mandarin, simplified-characters, direction-complement, complement, result-complement

I think one means it hasn’t happened yet and the other means it’s already happened, but I don’t really understand what that means when trying to translate into English or when trying to think of it in some kind of context.

Answer (score 6):

Without context, you can only break down the phrase into word types and follow the grammar rule to interpret it literally

> 吃(verb: eat) + 上(verb particle: successfully/ able to)+ 饭(noun: meals)

> **吃上饭** = successfully/ able to eat meal = **able to acquire and eat food**

> To check this structure is universal or not, replace the noun and see if it is still grammatical

> **吃上龙虾** = successfully/ able to eat lobster = **able to acquireand and eat lobster**

~

> 吃(verb: eat) + 下(verb particle: down) + 饭(noun: meal/ food)

> **吃下饭** = eat down a meal = **ingest food**

> To check this structure is universal or not, replace the noun and see if it is still grammatical

> **吃下毒药** = eat down poison  = **ingest poison**

Longer sentences can illustrate the functions of the phrases better

1a. 他窮得快**吃不上饭**了 = He is so poor that he'll soon **unable to acquire and eat food** (= can't afford food)

1b. 有工作才**吃得上饭** = You **can acquire and eat food** only when you have a job

2a. 他虛弱得**吃不下饭**了 = He is so weak that he **can't eat down food (= can't ingest food)**

2b. 他的病好了許多，已經**吃得下饭**了 = His body has recovered a lot, already **able to ingest food**

Studying the example, 吃上饭, and 吃下饭 mostly work with potential particles 得 or 不 (able/ unable) --> [吃(得)上饭], [吃(不)上饭]; [吃(得)下饭], [吃(不)下饭]

Answer (score 4):

忙了一天我终于`吃上饭`了 -> i finally managed to eat after a busy day

this emphasises being able to.

---

我心情不好，`吃`不`下饭` -> i'm not in the mood to eat

`下` emphasises "down"

the minimum requirement of eating is to swallow down the food, but i am not even able to do that because of bad mood.

---

我去学校的食堂`吃下饭` or 我去学校的食堂`吃`一`下饭` -> i'm gonna grab some food from the uni's cafe

in this example, `下` does not really mean "down" it's more of saying this is not going to take long.

take a computer analogy, think of this like a piece of code only costs very few cpu cycles

think of `一下` like a piece of code only costs explicitly 1 cpu cycle

Answer (score 1):

吃下饭：eat

我们还可以在电影开始前去外面吃下饭。
We can have dinner before the film starts.

吃上饭： have *something* to eat, however meagre, as opposed to nothing at all

他们已经四五天没吃上一顿像样的饭了。
They haven't had a decent meal in four or five days.